# Kendo-Ui Grid more than one column in edit popup

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Telerik's Kendo UI data grid in an asp.net core MVC project however I cannot figure out how I get my edit popup to show 2 or more columns so that i can have textboxes side by side to each other.I understand I need a view model to display custom but how does one create 2 rows in a custom edit popup.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Stock>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(180);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(180);
        columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(160);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(160);
    })

.ToolBar(toolbar =>
 {
     toolbar.Create();
     toolbar.Save();
 })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Pageable()
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Groupable()
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)

    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error"))

      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(true);
          model.Field(p => p.Name);
      })

    .Read("ReadStock", "Stock")
    .Update("Stock_Update", "Stock"))

   )
)
```

**Edit 2**

I have added the popup template but now for some reason it is not firing my update function. Any ideas why it's not hitting my update function.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Stock>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(180);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(180);
            columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(160);
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(160);
        })

    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
     {
         toolbar.Create();
         toolbar.Save();
     })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)

        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error"))

          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(true);
              model.Field(p => p.Name);
          })

        .Read("ReadStock", "Stock")
        .Update("Stock_Update", "Stock"))
    .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("StockEditorTemplate"))


       )
    )
```

Template Code

```
@model RoundTableDal.Models.Stock
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
<div class="k-edit-form-container">
    <h3>Customized Stock Edit</h3>
    <br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="k-edit-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="k-edit-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-field">
        @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.EndDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update Function**

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Stock_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Stock stockItem)    {
        if (stockItem != null && ModelState.IsValid)            {
            int x = await apiClient.PostUpdateStock(stockItem);
        }

        return Json(new[] {stockItem}.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

I am wondering is it cause i am dealing with multilingual

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>    {
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default",
   pattern: "{culture=en-gb}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   endpoints.MapRazorPages(); }); in my root path.
```

Comment: For anything beyond a basic UI, you need to create your own editor tempate. Sample project is [here](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/custom-popup-editor). Grid definition [here](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/custom-popup-editor/KendoUIMVC5/Views/Home/Index.cshtml), template definition [here](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/custom-popup-editor/KendoUIMVC5/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml). Might find better examples on SO.

Comment: Its a good grid and get the concept easy my boostrap is not as good as c# how would i create two text fields side by side in that scenerio @SteveGreene

Comment: @SteveGreene I got the form sorted out thank u but for some reason, the popup is not hitting my update command some reason any idea as to why

Comment: You've got duplicate `.Editable(...)` and not sure you need the `.ServerOperation(false)` or the `AcceptVerbs`. Make sure you reference `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`.